# Cocoa Loading a nib template multiple times, simultaneously

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, view, nib

I have two nib files, one that will open at startup and another that will be loaded when a user clicks a button. The first one works fine, and the second one works the first time. The thing is that I want to load the second nib file several times separately whenever the button is pressed. Currently I'm using this:

```
- (IBAction)startAction:(id)sender {

NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];

[nib instantiateNibWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
```

But this *reloads* the nib that is already being shown, I want a new view to be loaded separately. They each display some user input which will be different for each view loaded, so I imagine it has to be made into separate objects so they don't interfere with one another. I can tell the nib is being loaded because a timer is displayed, and every time enter is pressed the timer counts faster, meaning they're running simultaneously on the same view, I want them running simultaneously on separate views. I found the code I'm using in the documentation, but it had this written under it:

```
// At this point, our outlets to inside this nib will be properly setup. It is important to note
// that they will get overwritten when this is called again!
```

So I'm not sure if what I want can be done using this code, or if I should use something completely different.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the nib file has been loaded, the [`NSNib`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSNib_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object uses the bundle’s resource map to locate additional resources referenced by the nib. If you specified `nil` for the bundle parameter, the [`NSNib`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSNib_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object looks for those resources in the bundle associated with the class of the nib file’s owner instead. You should instantiating your nib with different owner object.

Comment: Should there be a different owner object for each individual view?

Comment: Also, I really have no idea how to do any of this. What bundle should I use? I need the view to load about 9 times, is that one object each? I don't know how to programmatically make a new object or assign it.